# jQuery Selector wild card selector attribute as object parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use the progressbar UI widget on multiple elements.  The value I want to pass is the actual attribute of the element.  How do I achieve this?

I have tried these but they don't work:

```
$('[id^=pkg]').progressbar({value: $(this).attr('value')});
$('[id^=pkg]').progressbar({value: $([id^=pkg]).attr('value')});
```

I do get a value for:

```
$([id^=pkg]).attr('value')
```

Apologies but this was missing:

```
<div id="pkg1" value="30"><div class="progress-label"></div></div>
```

Which required parseInt().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id^=pkg]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.progressbar({
        value: $this.attr('value')
    });
});
```

Btw, It's better to use class name instead of `[id^=pkg]`

Comment: Thank's for the tip, I agree it is more elegant to use class name.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to iterate and initiate each at a time?

```
$('[id^=pkg]').each(function() {
  $(this).progressbar({value: $(this).attr('value')});
});
```

Option 1 Won't work because the value of `this` is not what you expect it to be.

```
$('[id^=pkg]').progressbar({value: $(this).attr('value')});
```